# php - How to ordering query result with answeroption float horizontal by a line

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to order my query as I show below. :)

Table **question**

```
id  question 
100  What is your name?  
101  What is your nick name?
```

Table **answer**

```
id answeroption  questionid
1  John  100 
2  Mike  100
3  Adam  100
4  Am   101 
5  Den  101
```

So,i want the result show like this,with answeroption float horizontal by a line :

```
id   question  answer1 answer2 answer3 
100    What is your name? John Mike Adam 
101    What is your nick name? Am Den
```

The function query i used but i'm stuck to fix for result that i want actually.

```
function test($con){
    $q = "select a.id, a.question, b.answeroption
            from question a
            inner join answer b
            on a.id = b.questionid
          ";
    $run = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
    return $row;
```

}

Comment: You need a dynamic pivot if you want separate answers.Put the data in sqlfiddle for easier testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and `GROUP BY`

```
 $q = "SELECT a.id, a.question, GROUP_CONCAT(b.answeroption) AS answeroptions
            FROM question a
                INNER JOIN answer b ON a.id = b.questionid
            GROUP BY a.id
          ";
```

Comment: thank sir,but how if I want to echo b.answeoption?.. my code like this `echo $row['answeroption']; ` I got message that " Undefined index: answeroption "

Comment: @den I have updated my answer to use the alias modifier `AS` `answeroptions` this will allow you to select it

Comment: oyeah..thanks @cmorrissey..it working right now .I want to ask a bit, if i want to insert in table  per column per answer how to extract answeroption? :D

Comment: @den with `GROUP_CONCAT(b.answeroption SEPARATOR '|')` you can see i set a separator, you can then use this to `$data = explode('|', $row['answeroptions']);` which will put the data into an array

Comment: Oh,thank @cmorrissey, I think I understand about it, thanks a lot for helping me..:thumb up: ;)